# angularjs expression with special character

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Some angular expressions contain special characters (e.g. '-'):

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="asset in assets">
  <td>{{asset.id}}</td>
  <td>{{asset.display-name}}</td>
  <td>{{asset.dns-name}}</td>
  <td>{{asset.link[0].uri}}</td>
</tr>
```

In above code: **`{{asset.display-name}}`** and **`{{asset.dns-name}}`** prints 0 which is not correct. How to escape part of an expressions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[*Square bracket notation*](http://www.javascripttoolbox.com/bestpractices/#squarebracket) will help you:

```
{{ asset['display-name'] }}
```